# Most local to global approach to number fields?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, local-field

My experience with algebraic numbery theory has been as follows:

I studied about number fields, extensions $Q$. That required dealing with Dedekind domains and proving various results such as unique factorziation, $\sum e_i d_i = [K:Q]$, inertial group, etc.

I am now studying about the algebraic theory of local fields where everything is much simpler (including all the claims above, with appropriate definitions).

I have yet to see a major result one can deduce about number fields via the local fields (I understand that class field will do), I would like to find a way to avoid having to prove the results in number fields that I mentioned above, and find a way to deduce them via the local methods.

Sadly the current method I'm aware of to connect a number field to an extension of $Q_p$ requires already knowing about unique factorization and the fractional ideals, you consider the evaluation by some prime over $p$ to embed your field in an extension of $Q_p$.

Is there a way to develop ANT from local fields?

Comment: Morally there shouldn't be, and morally you shouldn't want to. Global fields (or global objects in general) are infinitely richer than their local counterparts and, in particular, cannot be entirely described in purely local terms. Namely, there are very deep 'consistency' results needed to glue local information to global information. Written more symbolically there is a map 

$$\{\text{global objects}\}\to\prod_{\text{places } v}\{\text{local objects over }v\}$$

and this map, while sometimes injective, is very far from being surjective. There really is some magic glue necessary

Comment: between families of local objects necessary to obtain a global object. So, while you can study global objects by local objects we cannot completely replace global objects with a bunch of local objects. This is also desirable since it makes the global theory so much more powerful than their local counterparts.

Comment: ֲ@AlexYoucis Thanks, but there are may instances where this is done (I am not aware of the details yet, but Kronker weber, class field,...), so why shouldn't it be possible for the $\sum e_i f_i =n$?

Comment: Oh wow, I'm super sorry. I missed that you were asking for this. I mean you can prove a local formula of the form $ef=n$ and then use the fact that if you have an extension $E/F$ of number field and $v$ is a place of $F$ then $E\otimes_F F_v$ is isomorphic, as topological $F_v$-algebras, to $\displaystyle \prod_{w\mid v}E_w$. This allows you to deduce the result globally.

Comment: @AlexYoucis Thanks. I'm trying to formalize your cool solution. While it gives me a better understanding, I suspect you can't quite use it to actually prove the result since you want to understand the extensions coming from primes over your prime, and how it factorizes relating to properties of the extension.  In anyway I'm satisfied so thanks.